# ArangoDB AQL optimisation for a cluster configuration

Tags: arangodb, aql

With data structure like

```
Departure -> Trip -> Driver
```

using an [ArangoDB Spring Data](https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data) derived query in the Trip repository like `findByDriverIdNumberAndDepartureStartTimeBetween( String idNumber, String startTime, String endTime )` results in an AQL query like

```
WITH driver, departure 
FOR e IN trip 
    FILTER 
    (FOR e1 IN 1..1 OUTBOUND e._id tripToDriver FILTER e1.idNumber == '999999-9999' RETURN 1)[0] == 1 
    AND 
    (FOR e1 IN 1..1 INBOUND e._id departureToTrip FILTER e1.startTime >= '2019-08-14T00:00:00' AND e1.startTime <= '2019-08-14T23:59:59' RETURN 1)[0] == 1  
    RETURN e
```

which performs fine (~1s) with a single instance setup, but after setting up a cluster with the Kubernetes ArangoDB Operator with default settings (3 nodes and coordinators) the query time increased tenfold, which is is probably due to sharding and multi-machine communication to fulfil the query.

This attempt to optimise the query gave better results, query time around 3 to 4 seconds:

```
WITH driver, departure
FOR doc IN trip

    LET drivers = (FOR v IN 1..1 OUTBOUND doc tripToDriver RETURN v) 
    FILTER drivers[0].idNumber == '999999-9999'

    LET departures = (FOR v in 1..1 INBOUND doc departureToTrip RETURN v) 
    FILTER departures[0].startTime >= '2019-08-14T00:00:00' AND departures[0].startTime <= '2019-08-14T23:59:59'

    RETURN doc
```

But can I optimise the query further for the cluster setup, to come closer to the single instance query time of one second?

Comment: What indexes do you have setup? What does the query execution plan show? How are the tables sharded? Since you are just going one level in each traversal, have you considered just joining the tables? Are you using smart graphs? Did you try filtering the data using the path.vertex instead of vertex (although this should make not difference since you are just traversing one level, it does in multi level traversals)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but all collections used in this query have the default shard value of 1.  Joining the tables would require a common key between the documents, if I understand correctly, and the data in its current shape doesn't have those, only edge relations between the documents.